# How different is the answer's OS allowed to be?

Tags: discussion, support, answers

I sometimes see Windows answers which are removed because they are not helpful to Ubuntu users, even Mac answers, but what about answers that explain how to do something on Mint (and it is clear that they are using Mint)? Or what about Elementary OS? Or Kali Linux? Are only Ubuntu answers allowed or are answers like [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/695968/364819) allowed too (by the way that answer doesn't actually work for me, so it's possibly just a Kali Linux thing)?

Is it just favourable that they are for Ubuntu and not for another Linux distribution? Or does it depend on the answer and whether it is unhelpful because they are not using Ubuntu? Or are they not allowed at all?

I would like for someone to set this straight as I'm really not sure where to draw the line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Note that I'm not encouraging people to post answers that work for other distributions; I'm rather discouraging downvoting / flagging / voting to delete already posted answers mentioning another distribution that work for Ubuntu.**

---

Would you keep an answer that works, if it works also on Debian? I guess yes.

As long as they work, they're "allowed" (meaning: not deserveful to be deleted).

Many GNU/Linux distributions are so similar in certain aspects that I wouldn't be surprised that even a highly system-dependent solution that works for distribution X would work for Ubuntu as well.

However indeed downvote / flag / vote to delete those that don't.

Answer (score 3):

I think the same goes for answers as it does questions. Ubuntu and its official flavours are allowed, otherwise it belongs on the Unix & Linux site. As you pointed out, the Kali Linux solution did not work for you. If it's an Ubuntu problem, you expect an Ubuntu solution.